# New NexiGo WebCam working as expected, however, the Cheese application starts recording at the time the cam was plugged in

Tags: video, webcam, recording, display-driver

Each-time I try to record myself using the cheese application, the app starts recording at the time that my web cam was plugged in. In other words, each recording, starts at `00:00`, but instead of ticking to `00:00:01`, Cheese will skip a bunch of time, and start at a silly value, like `02:23:07` (*2hrs 23min 07sec*), where it will then start recording. The time it chooses to start recording at is not arbitrary, its exactly the same amount of time that has elapsed since I first plugged the Web-cam in. So, for instance, if you use the command below...

#### `ls -lt /dev/video*`

...it will show you when the **web-cam** was fist plugged in, if I subtract that time, from the current time, I get the value that cheese starts recording at.

---

If someone knows exactly what's going on, that would be great, however, if someone knows how I can troubleshoot this issue, that's just as well.

**Bonus question:** *Is this issue being caused by cheese, or by the web-cam/web-cam drivers?*

Comment: According to [this Fedora bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1884260) this is related to PipeWire. It's a bug, of course.

Comment: @DanielB Nice find Daniel, thank you for the link.